# Java toString()-method doesn't work for my class

Tags: java, printing, tostring

```
import java.io.*;

public class Bewertung {
  int schwarze;
  int weisse;
```

This class constructs objects, that have to attributes schwarze and weisse. Default-Constructor:

```
  public Bewertung() {
  schwarze = 0;
  weisse = 0;
  }
```

Constructor:

```
  public Bewertung(int sw, int ws) {
  schwarze = sw;
  weisse = ws;
  }
```

To-String Method. Here is a mistake somewhere, cause I get some crazy stuff in the terminal when trying to give an object out by using this method.

```
  public String toString() {
    int x = this.schwarze;
    int y = this.weisse;

    char x2 = (char) x;
    char y2 = (char) y;
    String Beschreibung = x2 + "," + y2;
    return Beschreibung; 
  }
```

This method checks if two Objects are the same by comparing their attributes.

```
public boolean equals(Bewertung o) {  
 if (this.schwarze == o.schwarze && this.weisse == o.weisse) {
  return true;
}
else return false;
}
```

This Method creates a new object with the attributes you give in in the terminal, works fine.

```
public static Bewertung readBewertung() throws IOException {
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
System.out.println("Gib die Zahl fuer Schwarz ein.");
String zeile;
    int wert=0;

    zeile=br.readLine();
    int eingabe1=(new Integer(zeile)).intValue();
System.out.println("Gib die Zahl fuer Weiss ein.");
zeile=br.readLine();
    int eingabe2=(new Integer(zeile)).intValue();

Bewertung neueBewertung = new Bewertung(eingabe1, eingabe2);
return neueBewertung;

}
```

Main-Method: Here we construct two Objects, that construct 2 new objects with the readBewertung()-Method, and then we try to print them and do some other stuff. Everything
but the printing works fine.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
try 
{
Bewertung Bewertung1 = MeineBewertung1.readBewertung();
  System.out.println(Bewertung1.toString());
  Bewertung Bewertung2 = MeineBewertung2.readBewertung();
  System.out.println(Bewertung2.toString());
  if (Bewertung1.equals(Bewertung2)) {
  System.out.println("Die beiden Bewertungen sind identisch!");
  }
}
catch ( IOException e)
{
}


}

}
```

The problem: I get some squares instead of the Objects cast in a String how intended. I don't know what is wrong, but the mistake has to be anywhere in the to.String()-method.

Answer (score 4):

This:

```
char x2 = (char) x;
char y2 = (char) y;
```

Is your problem. You're casting and assigning an `int` to `char` ... which means you now have the character in whatever your charset is with that integer value. In your case ... there isn't a printable character with that value, so you get "little squares" (In a different terminal you might see question marks).

To better illustrate, try this:

```
int a = 65;
char c = (char)a;
System.out.println(c);
```

Provided you're using UTF-8 or some other charset that includes US-ASCII in the first byte code points you'd see:

> A

Because `65` is the value for `A` in ASCII (See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#ASCII_printable_characters)

Don't do that. Remove those lines, and get the textual representations of the integers which will automatically happen when using String concatenation:

```
String Beschreibung = x + "," + y;
```

There are other ways to do this (For example `String.valueOf()` and `String.format()`) but this is the simplest.

(Also, don't capitalize variable names. Variables in Java should be camelCase and start lowercase.)

Answer (score 2):

You can't translate from number to char like you're trying since all you'll see are the ASCII representation of the number which is not what you want. Instead why not let String do the heavy lifting for you by using `String.format(...)`:

```
public String toString() {
 int x = this.schwarze;
 int y = this.weisse;

 return String.format("%d, %d", x, y);
}
```

Also, please learn and use proper Java naming conventions. Methods and variables should begin with a lower case letter.

Comment: You probably mean from number to char.

Comment: Okay, thanks, are there any Notes where I can read the naming conventions?